# Visual Studio - Javascript UWP - Visual Assets via vector graphic

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

[this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/One-Dev-Minute/Creating-Hosted-Web-Apps-with-Project-Westminster) inspired me to build some app for our companys own RocketChat.

Anyway, I took a look at the *package.appxmanifest* and especially the *Visual Assets*.
Since I am a webdeveloper I'm asking myself if it's possible to provide some simple vector graphic, instead of prodiving "the same" image in these many different sizes?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible to provide a single vector graphic, you need to generate a separate file for each asset type and size.

Required assets are NOT simply the same graphic with a different size, there are guidelines (e.g margins and colors) for each type of asset that you need to take care of. Read [Guidelines for tile and icon assets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt412102.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more info.